# Offline embedded realtime routing

Tags: c++, dictionary, routes, gps, embedded

I am currently working on a senior design project for school and have come across a design issue that i do not know how to solve. I need to have realtime, offline routing for an embedded walking application.

I have not been able to find any libraries that suit my need. I understand i might either have to make my own vectorized map of my local town or routing algorithm. I will not go into much detail what my project entails but it does not require a large map. Maybe a 5x5 mile grid. The maps can be loaded by SD if need to be changed.

I see there are GpsMid, YOURs, and others all using OpenStreetMap data.

We will have a TI micro-controller for processing and GPS card for real time lat/lon I just do not know how to take the real time info and route using a static map.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well versed in what is typically used for real-time routing with GPS and vectorized maps, but I can recommend some general algorithms that can be used as tools to help you get your project done.

A* search is a pretty typical path finding algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star

Depending on how you organize your data, you may also find to Dijkstra's algorithm to be helpful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

These algorithms are popular enough that you should be able to find example code in whatever language you want, although I'd be very skeptical of the quality. I'd recommend writing your own, since you are in school, as it'd be beneficial for you to have written and debugged them on your own at least once in your career. When you are done, you'll have a tried and true implementation to call your own.

Comment: thanks for your input. I am very familiar with routing algorithms so I am not too worried about them. I am more concerned with taking in a lat/lon from my Gps card and having software to do real time routing with the person based on a preset map. I am just not sure how to make the maps to identify what is a road / street / etc. and then route based on nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me there are two parts to this:

1 - Identifying map data that tells you what's a road/path (potential route), I would expect this is already in the data in some way. It could be as simple as which colour any given line is.

2 - Calculating a route over those paths. This is well documented/discussed and there are plenty of algorithms etc. out there on the problem. These days it's hardly worth trying very hard for elegance/efficiency, you can just throw CPU cycles at it until an answer pops out.

Also, should this be tagged [homework] ?